# Изменение высоты дочернего элемента

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

Нужно сделать, чтоб высота дочернего элемента не наследовалась родителем.
С position: absolute не получается.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: приведите ваш код для большей ясности вопроса!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно использовать `position: relative`

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

li {
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  display: block;
  float: left;
  width: 25%;
  padding: 15px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background-color: #61CDFF;
  position: relative;
}
li:hover {
  top: -10px;
  padding: 25px 15px;
  background-color: #4BBDF2;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>ГЛАВНАЯ</li>
  <li>ПРОГРАММЫ</li>
  <li>ДРАЙВЕРЫ</li>
  <li>СТРИМЫ</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Кто и за что, интересно, поставил минус?

Comment: не я, но предполагаю из-за отсутствия наработок))))

Comment: @HamSter, ну, в этом-то вопросе всё и так понятно, без наработок. типа из принципа? :)

Comment: ну да, думаю так)

Comment: это я постарался...

Comment: @Air, и зачем, интересно?

Comment: @HamSter, дал точный ответ

Comment: @Air, в этом вопросе всё ясно и без наработок - к чему такая тупая принципиальность?